# macOS cmake display"install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target "SO_kolev"."

Tags: c++, cmake

When My MacBook run cmake, it display

```
install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "SO_kolev".
```

How can I fix it?

The following is my cmake file:

```
# Create shared library with a generated dictionary.
  add_library(SO_${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} D_${PROJECT_NAME}.cxx)

# Link against shared library and list of ROOT libraries
  target_link_libraries(SO_${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_NAMES})

# Find location of the enrty point file (main.c*)
  file(GLOB_RECURSE MAIN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cxx ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c)
  list(FILTER MAIN INCLUDE REGEX "main\\.c")
# message(STATUS "Found entry point file: ${MAIN}")

# Create the main program using the library.
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SO_${PROJECT_NAME})

# Compose the install target
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} SO_${PROJECT_NAME} 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${ROOTSYS}/lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libD_${PROJECT_NAME}.rootmap
        DESTINATION $ENV{ROOTSYS}/lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libD_${PROJECT_NAME}_rdict.pcm
        DESTINATION /usr/local/bin)
```

Comment: As you could guess from the error message, the comment in your code "# Create shared library with a generated dictionary." is not quite correct: the library is actually a **static**, not a *shared* one. By default, CMake selects type of the library accoring to  [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html#variable:BUILD_SHARED_LIBS) variable. If you want to create a static library in any case, then use `STATIC` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

When installed with [install(TARGETS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/command/install.html#targets) command, a **static library** is treated as `ARCHIVE` kind of artifact, so CMake needs to know into which directory to install such kind of artifacts.

This directory is specified with `DESTINATION` argument, but your `install` command has only directories for `RUNTIME` and `LIBRARY` artifacts. So you need to add appropriate argument for `ARCHIVE`:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} SO_${PROJECT_NAME} 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${ROOTSYS}/lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${ROOTSYS}/lib)
```

---

Since CMake 3.14 some kind of artifacts has default values for installation directories, so `DESTINATION` argument for them is no longer required. This is explicitely noted in the documentation:

> For regular executables, static libraries and shared libraries, the `DESTINATION` argument is not required. For these target types, when `DESTINATION` is omitted, a default destination will be taken from the appropriate variable from GNUInstallDirs, or set to a built-in default value if that variable is not defined.